# Ember.js Handlebars bindings logical not

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Is there a logical not for handlebars bindings with Ember.js?**

Suppose I have a ember view that I want to bind to a value

```
{{Ember.Button disabledBinding="view.controller.some_value"}}
```

I only want the button to be disabled if `some_value` is `false`. The code above makes it disabled if `some_value` is `true`.

One approach to fixing this would be to have a complementary computed value on the controller. *excuse my coffeescript*

```
opposite_some_value: (->
    if @get('some_value') == true
        return false
    else
        return true
).property 'some_value'
```

But this seems clunky.

Comment: Handlebars supports the logical not in `if` statements through the complementary `unless` statement. http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a property with the inverted value is the way to go. You can use binding helper for this: `oppositeValueBinding: Ember.Binding.not('some_value')`.

Also note the `Ember.Button` is deprecated and you should use the `{{action}}` helper instead.

**UPDATE**

In newer versions of Ember.js, it's `oppositeValue: Ember.computed.not('some_value')`.

Comment: thats not a computed property.  thats a binding with a tranform.

Comment: Bummer... Wish it could just be handled within handlebars. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't push such logic into the template. This is should be handled in the View/Controller.

Comment: @pangratz I generally agree that logic shouldn't be in the template, but taking an inverse value hardly counts. I don't see this being any more complex than an `if` statement in a template.

Comment: The way to bind inverted values is now as follows: `oppositeValueBinding: Ember.computed.not('some_value')`. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed.js